# Facebook instant game prerequisite

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I am new to publishing on facebook platform especially instant games. In a checklist before submitting for review, I saw that I should add an instruction details on how to perform in app purchase otherwise I cannot or the submit for review button will not be active. Is it ok that I put that my game is not supporting in app purchase at this time? Will my submission will be rejected? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't support In App Purchases you should not submit for In App Purchases when you submit for review.

Do not click "Add to Submission" for In App Purchases. Your submission should look like mine below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris. Although I face another problem, before I can submit for review, it is now asking an apple develoer ID which I don't have.

Comment: Hi Margallo, you will need one unfortunately. This is a requirement for all Instant Games as they are playable on iOS. You can register as an individual developer with Apple for US$99 a year here: https://developer.apple.com/